# Can't create a new menu with Alacarte

Tags: alacarte

I can't create a new menu with Alacarte in Ubuntu 16.04. 
When I want to create a new menu, the Accept button is always disabled.

Answer (score 1):

OK so I think your launch command might be invalid. Say you want to launch `~/Downloads/CLion/clion.sh`, that would not be a valid Alacarte command. You need to first put it in quotes: `"~/Downloads/CLion/clion.sh"`, and then add `%f` on the end after the quotes.

`"~/Downloads/CLion/clion.sh" %f` should do the trick. Also make sure that the file is allowed to execute. To do this:

- Right click on the file and click properties.
- Select the permissions tab and enable "allow executing file as program"

[image: Executing file]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, I don't understand why but it seems that alacarte no longer likes spaces or quotes in the Command field. My command was

```
"/home/xyz/app/app.sh" %f
```

This should produce a valid .desktop file according to the gnome specs (see https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/) but alacarte doesn't like it. The %f apparently allows gnome to pass a single file as a parameter when running the application so you can double click files to open with that program or right click files and use "Open With". If you don't need that functionality then just delete the quotes, spaces and the %f. Otherwise I guess just find the .desktop file and edit manually.

Answer (score 0):

The trick for me is that I needed to add the icon, by clicking on the left icon placeholder. Then command:
"myPath/myFile.sh"
Note there is no "." at the beginning of the path.